# Postfix + dovecot, disable authentication on port 25

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, sasl

I use postfix 2.9.6 on ubuntu 12.04 (with dovecot if that matters).

I'm trying to disable auth on port 25 and only allow it on port 587, so that I can receive mails normally from other servers but that clients can only connect  on port 587 to send mails.

I tried following answers on here and on found on google, but whatever settings I change I'm always able to connect on port 25.

relevant part of my master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no

submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject
```

my entire main.cf:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
myhostname = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2 #( Postfix ≥ 2.6 milter_protocol = 6, Postfix ≤ 2.5 milter_protocol = 2 )
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12345
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12345
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 2
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove smtpd_recipient_restrictions from main.cf and change master.cf as follows:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=none
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks

submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
 -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
 -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject
```

Please Be Care Full bad configuration on  `smtpd_client_restrictions` parameters may dangerous